# Are some items only available through "event" missions?

Tags: star-wars-assault-team

Playing the standard promotion missions, I pretty much get the same set of items every time.

For example, in Weapon Promotion Tier 3, I get the Riot Gun, Electro Sword, and Blast Rifle all the time. However, I can't find the blaster frame (also a tier 3). It could just be that I need to play that mission a whole bunch more, but its making me wonder:

Are some items only available in the "event" (ie Weapons Wednesday) missions, even though their tier is available in the standard missions? The in-game help suggests some cards can only be achieved by playing in the Arena, but mentions characters specifically (not promotion items).

To be super clear, is there any Tier 1,2, or 3 item that is not given though the standard promotion missions? Obviously Tier 4 and 5 items are going to be difficult to get unless you go through the event missions.

Comment: I can't answer for sure but I've been trying to farm promotion items for luke skywalker today and have run the force friday promotion items (smaller one) a ton and seen loads of some items but not the one I need for luke (the training remote). So it might be a rarity for items rather than a location availability.

Comment: It is there (got it last night) :). Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Was that from the normal or the force friday missions out of interest? I've made about 17000 credits farming for my promotion items...

Comment: As I recall the training remote is the Tier 4 item, so I got it through Force Friday. The tier 3 items I got normally (4 energy per attempt instead of 6).

Answer (score 1):

Sabaac Cards and the Medal of Alderaan are only in Arena Crates, so I'd say it's really rare since arena crates now only go up to Tier 3.

Answer (score 1):

Sabaac Cards are a tier 4 promotion item which are available through the daily promotion missions.  Tier 5 promotion items, however, are only available from arena crates I believe.

Comment: So you cannot get them through the daily "special" missions?

Answer (score 0):

From the runs I've done on it so far looks like everything except Tier 5 Promo Items are getable. I've found everything except Sabaac Cards (Solo Tier 5), Bowcaster (Chewie), Medal of Alderaan (Leia), some force item for Luke. Been grinding missions for weeks now and those items just don't drop at all

Comment: Given the "standard" mission tiers stop at 3, I wasn't expecting to get 5s out of them (I read somewhere that 4 drops happen rarely in 3, but never 5 drops as you seem to have experienced). Since I am curious about Tier 3 items in a Tier 3 mission, I'm not sure this answers the question. Thank you for your response though!

Answer (score 0):

I would say the upper tier card for promotion is extremely rare and needs to be found in the promotion area but I think the rarity of it forces you to use gems instead of grinding for it.

Answer (score 0):

I received the Sabacc cards three times this week on the smuggler T4 weekly (6 cost).  I assume they just have low drop rates, but I have all the T5 items from the weeklies, just trying to get some of the T4 now.

Answer (score -1):

Sabaac Cards (Solo Tier 5), Bowcaster (Chewie), Medal of Alderaan (Leia) can only be found in crates

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: In which crates? Arena crates? If yes, which ones? Only gem crates? If yes which ones?